# Comparing values within lists

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm new to stackoverflow but have a question regarding my model.

My model consists of two breeds of agents (fishers and processors). Currently I have two fishers and two processors. Both breeds have a certain price-perception variable called: price-perception-fisher and price-perception-processor. Fishers go out fishing and once the ship is full (catch = 750) they return to one of the processors. This is done by this function:

```
to return-from-fishing ;; makes fishers return once they have a certain amount of fish 
  if epi-catch >= 1000 or exp-meso-catch >= 750                          
    [move-to one-of processors     
     set arrived-at-processor? true
     ]
end
```

What I would like to do is compare the price perception of a fisher to the price-perception of the processor that the fisher visits.

Currently I have tried to do this by creating two lists; one for the price perception of processors and one for the price perception of fishers. I compare them using list-transactions `(map > list-of-fishers-price-perceptions list-of-processors-price-perceptions)`

What this does is iterate through both lists and compare the values in the list. However the problem is that the values are compared randomly and I want the fisher to compare his own price with that of the processor he visits. If the price-perception-fisher is higher to the price-perception-processors the fisher moves to another processor, else they will peform a transaction

An example from my model is as follows:

Variables of turtles are initialised as follows:

```
   set fisher 0 price-perception-fisher 12.5 
   set fisher 1 price-perception-fisher 15
   set processor 2 price-perception-processor 10 
   set processor 3 price-perception-processor 15
```

As fishers randomly move to one of the processors, both fishers could move to processor 2. The expected output would then be:

fisher 0 (12.5) moves to processor 2 (10) and as 12.5 >= 10, the value should be true

fisher 1 (15) moves to processor 2 (15) and as 15 >= 15, the value should be true

However I get this output, because the lists don't understand that the fishers have moved to just processor 2 and therefore they compare the price-perception-fisher 0 with price-perception-processor 3, while I want the comparison between price-perception-fisher 0 with price-perception-processor 3 in this case.

```
[15 12.5] ; fishers price perceptions
[10 15] ; processors price perceptions
[true false]
```

Would there be a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it: just make each turtle directly look into that processor's price perception. There is no need to take into account the values from all turtles and all processors.

There are a couple of ways to do this.

If it is absolutely and structurally certain that there will never be more than one processor per patch, you can do:

```
to check-perceptions
  ask fishers with [arrived-at-processor?] [
    ifelse (price-perception-fisher < [price-perception-processor] of one-of processors-here)
      [perform-transaction]
      [find-another-processor]
  ]
end
```

The `processors-here` reporter (see [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here)) reports an agentset. If you are sure that there cannot be more than one processor per patch, it means that `one-of processors-here` will inevitably report the processor that the fisher is visiting, because it would be the only one populating the `processors-here` agentset.

If you prefer to avoid this approach because you don't like using an agentset when you know you want to refer only to a specific agent, you can take this other approach adding a fishers-own variable:

```
fishers-own [
  ; ...
  ; Here there are the other fishers-own variables
  ; ...
  current-processor
]

to return-from-fishing
  if epi-catch >= 1000 or exp-meso-catch >= 750 [
    set current-processor one-of processors
    move-to current-processor
    set arrived-at-processor? TRUE
  ]
end


to check-perceptions
  ask fishers with [arrived-at-processor?] [
    ifelse (price-perception-fisher < [price-perception-processor] of current-processor)
      [perform-transaction]
      [find-another-processor]
  ]
end
```

This way, `current-processor` will avoid any ambiguity should there ever be more than one processor per patch, and even from a logical point of view it will be a variable specifically thought for identifying an agent (instead of an agentset).

Of course, in case `find-another-processor` is executed, you need to remember to assign the new processor to `current-processor`.